# Как убрать редирект на https протокол

Tags: https, редирект

Возможно ли через htaccess убрать редирект на https версию сайта, и сделать что бы он открывался через http? Или это только через хостинг делается?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http

Comment: У вас тут нет редиректа на https. Он где-то в другом месте включен. А можеть у вас и сервер не apache.

Comment: При переходе по ссылке на мой сайт, браузер ругается на незащищенное соединение, и рядом со ссылкой на сайт указан протокол https, он перечеркнут красным цветом. 

Только не могу понять откуда взялся https, если я его не подключал. Подумал что стоит редирект с http на https, но видимо проблема в другом :(

Comment: А не подскажете, где еще может быть включен редирект на https?

Comment: Там ещё nginx'а помимо апача нет на сервае?